# question mark converted to %3F

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I am doing api call to get next 50 products from shopify products api
in first call using

```
/admin/api/2021-07/products.json
```

I get my 50 products and then I use the Link property to get the next 50 products
but when i hit the url it changes encodes the "?" to "%3F"

```
/admin/api/2021-07/products.json?limit=50&page_info=eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0MzgwNjE5OTk3MzIyLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiRHJvcC1D
```

- 

### Error i get upon debugging is following and in it my url is changed as i mentioned and if I hit the url in new tab by removing %3f and adding ? in its place it displays next 50 products

```
Client error: `GET https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/products.json%3Fpage_info=eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0MzgwNjE5OTk3MzIyLCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiRHJvcC1D ▶
      {"errors":"Not Found"}
```

I am using OSISET package
for my first call

```
$productsall = $shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/2021-07/products.json')['body']['container'];
```

and for my second call

```
$nextPageLink = $productsall ['link']['container']['next'];
$url = '?limit=250&page_info='.$nextPageLink;
$productsall = $shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/2021-07/products.json'.$url)['body']['container'];
```

Comment: How are you calling your API ?

Comment: I am adding this to my question for better visual representation

Comment: maybe `$shop->api()->rest()` has a third parameter specifically for the get-parameters. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: You guessed it right 
I looked into the documentation of OSISET package and found out that query parameter needs to be passed as third parameter in array format

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

I looked into the documentation of OSISET package and found out that query parameter needs to be passed as third parameter in array format

```
$request = $shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/customers/search.json', ['query' => "phone:{$phone}"]);
```

*Reference: https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki/Usage*